# Is there a difference between using this.props vs props in React?

Tags: reactjs

After you've defined `this`, is there a difference between using `this.props` and `props`?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    input: this.props.input,
    input2: props.input2
  };
}
```

In this case, what the difference between `input` and `input2` here?

Comment: console.log(props === this.props); // true -- so it's the same object

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The rules for ES2015 (ES6) classes basically come down to:

> In a child class constructor, **this** cannot be used until **super** is called.
>
> ES6 class constructors MUST call **super** if they are subclasses, or they must explicitly return some object to take the place of the one that was not initialized.

So as the **super(props)** is called in the constructor. props and this.props are same. so,

```
props === this.props // true
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically, it's same in this case, but if you consider the whole component then `props` can only be available if you pass `props` as function argument such as below example

```
componentWillMount(){
  this.someFunc(this.props);
}

componentWillReciveProps(nextProps){
  this.someFunc(nextProps);
}

someFunc(props) {
 ...... 
 // in here props and this.props are completely different
 as props is you latest props while this.props can be you previous props
}
```

while you can access `this.props` from anywhere of you component, i hope this gives you the idea

Answer (score 3):

No diffrence.

```
props === this.props // true
```

Answer (score 0):

no difference after you called super(props) in your constructor.
You can read more in-depth about it here: https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/